# Laravel 7 artisan migrate crashes because database not yet migrated

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, laravel-artisan

I work on a webapp in Laravel 7. I created a migration to add some new columns to a table.  Then I added code to work on those columns. All went fine.

However when I merged the new code to a new branch and tried to run the migrations to add the fields they require, I got an SQL error message telling me the some columns are missing.

It seems that **running the php artisan migrate** (or any other artisan commands) will **execute  the web.php** file that already **refers (indirectly) to the new columns** that are not yet there causing this error message. Please see below the stack trace showing this:

```
[2022-02-27 16:28:08] local.ERROR: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'LARAVEL_LOCALE' in 'field list' (SQL: select `ID`, `LARAVEL_LOCALE` from `LANGUAGE`) {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException(code: 42S22): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'LARAVEL_LOCALE' in 'field list' (SQL: select `ID`, `LARAVEL_LOCALE` from `LANGUAGE`) at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/gng2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:671)
```

...

```
#6 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/gng2/app/GNG/GNGLangDAO.php(24): Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder->get()
#7 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/gng2/routes/web.php(26): App\\GNG\\GNGLangDAO->loadAllLocales()
#8 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/gng2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteFileRegistrar.php(35): require('/Applications/M...')
```

It sounds a bit strange to me that **running php artisan migrate basically requires that migrations were already done**. Is there any way to avoid executing the web.php file when running the migrations or can you recommend any other solution to the problem?

Thanks,
W.

Comment: You may be doing some DB work in you service providers

Comment: The `RouteServiceProvider` will load all the routes regardless of whether you are running commands or making a web and that is what is loading `web.php` so keep that in mind when writing your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved the problem by separating the migration and the code into two separate branches and committing them separately. This was lower risk for me than modifying the code for such a single time problem.

Answer (score 1):

if you are running queries on Service Provider then you need to check if the app running on the console in ServiceProvider

```
if(App::runningInConsole())
{
  // app is running in console
}
```